# UV box textures different dimension

Tags: texturing

I have a problem with 2 object,
I would like the same size of the texture, in the two objects, without uv mapping (given the complexity of the objects).
What can I do?
thank you[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fast way is to use Box projection.

1. Set *Image* projection to *Box*
2. Change coordinates from *UV* to *Object*
3. In *Texture Coordinate > Object* field, target any object (I used an empty)

[image]